# Get my Attribute in details.phtml file on Product Page

Tags: magento2, attributes, custom-attributes

I need to get my Attribute code and it should be printed its values on **details.phtml** in my theme's template.

I have tried below but no luck.

```
$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('identifier'); 
if ($attribute) 
{ 
echo $attr_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); 
}
```

Any other ideas to get this?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure **Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront** Attribute option set as `Yes`.

You can check this from backend `Stores >> Attributes - Products`. On Attribute Edit page, check the `Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront` option in `Storefront Properties` Tab.

[image]

Comment: I have already set Attribute option set as Yes

Answer (score 0):

If you need to show custom attribute on product view page after sku then you can add your custom file and call this attribute.

create or edit `catalog_product_view.xml` file into your them and just put the bwllow code,

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.stock.sku">            
   <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product_view_style" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/identifier.phtml" before="-"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Now create `identifier.phtml` in appropiate path and call your custom attribute like that,

```
<?php
$_product = $this->getProduct();
?>
<div class="product attribute style">
   <strong class="type"><?php echo __('Identifier: ')?></strong>
   <div class="value" itemprop="style">
      <?php echo $_product->getData('identifier') ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope it's help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your newly created attribute from "**Unassigned Attributes**" to placed under "**Product Details**" listing in "**Attribut Set**".

You can check through **STORES** >> **ATTRIBUTES** >> **Attribute Sets**

Answer (score 0):

> it will help you to show your attribute on frontend.

```
helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_product = $block->getProduct(); 

$data = explode(',',$_product->getData('attribute_name'));

if(count($data) > 1)
{ 

   $attr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('custom_mask');
   $attrTestLabel = $attr->getStoreLabel(); echo $attrTestLabel; 
 
   foreach($data as $key => $value):                 
        $attr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('custom_mask');          

        if ($attr->usesSource()): 

         $option_value = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($value);
         echo $option_value; 

        endif;
        endforeach;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Get Custom Attribute on Product Page in details.phtml file. You can use this code.

```
<?php echo $_product->getData('identifier'); ?>
```